# One-to-Many Relationship in BiqQuery

Tags: google-bigquery, data-modeling

Suppose I've got entities `A`, `B`, and `C` with `one-to-many` relationships to store in BigQuery.

```
A -- (one to many) --> B --- (one to many) --> C
```

For a "regular" SQL database I'd create tables `A`, `B` and `C` with their primary keys and foreign keys in `A` and `B` based on the primary keys of `B` and `C`.

Would it work for BigQuery ? Would it better to denormalize that structure and store all `A`, `B`, and `C` in one table ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's say each produce can be produced in different farms, and each farms has a number of different employees.

In BigQuery, there's nothing wrong with having 3 tables and a relationship between them - but you might also want to take advantage of BigQuery's nested and repeated columns support.

For this made up example, we could model it up as follows:

```
SELECT 'tomato' produce, STRUCT<farm ARRAY<STRUCT<farm_id string, employee ARRAY<STRUCT<name string>>>>>(
  [
    STRUCT('farm1' AS farm_id, [STRUCT('employee1' AS name), STRUCT('employee2')] AS employee ) 
     , ('farm2', [STRUCT('employee3' AS name), STRUCT('employee4')])
     , ('farm3', [STRUCT('employee5' AS name), STRUCT('employee6')])
  ]) AS farms
UNION ALL
SELECT 'lettuce', STRUCT<ARRAY<STRUCT<farm_id string, employee ARRAY<STRUCT<name string>>>>>(
  [
    STRUCT('farm4' AS farm_id, [STRUCT('employee7' AS name), STRUCT('employee8')] AS employee ) 
     , ('farm5', [STRUCT('employee9' AS name)])
  ]) AS farms
```

[image]

*Q: Would it make sense to model it like this?*

*A: Depends.*

As Lloyd says:

> Nested records have a couple of advantages when scanning over a distributed dataset. First, they do not require joins. This means that computations can be faster and scan much less data than if you had to rejoin the extra data each time you use it.
>
> Nested structures are essentially pre-joined tables. And, because data is stored columnarly, if you don't reference the nested column, there is no added expense to the query. If you do reference the nested column, the logic is identical to a colocated join.
>
> The other advantage that nested structures bring is that they avoid repeating data that would have to be repeated in a wide, denormalized table. In other words, for a person who's lived in five cities, a wide denormalized table would contain all of their info in five rows (one for each of the cities they'd lived in). In a nested structure, the repeated information only takes one row, since the array of five cities can be contained in a single row and only unnested when needed.

- https://discourse.looker.com/t/nested-data-in-bigquery-repeated-records/4174

Meanwhile querying will be harder for users and tools not used to deal with nested data.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I would prefer 3 tables with relationship but I am afraid of join performance. The tables may contains dozens of millions of records. Will the performance be an issue in this case ?

Comment: No need to optimize early. I would switch models if get to a point where performance is an issue - OR - if a nested table would make the job easier for people analyzing.

Comment: I think one big table for `A`, `B`, and `C` will be easier for analysts and simpler to program.